# Para que sirve la función write?

Tags: c

Me gustaria saber para que sirve la función write, que valores hay que poner y que significan.
o sea... que significa lo siguiente:

```
void  ft_putchar(char c)
{
      write(1,&c, 1);
 }
```

gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido. Necesitamos contexto para poder responderte. De lo contrario solo podemos partir de suposiciones. Por ejemplo, en qué sistema operativo estás trabajando. Cada uno brinda diferentes funciones además de implementar el estándar.

Comment: `write()` envía bytes (que normalmente representan caracteres, pero no necesariamente) hacia un flujo de salida (el primer parámetro), que suele ser un fichero previamente abierto con `open()` (aunque no en tu caso). El segundo parámetro es la dirección donde están los bytes a enviar y el tercero es el número de bytes a enviar.   En cambio en tu caso el flujo de salida es `1` que representa la salida estándar (es decir, la terminal), la dirección es la de la variable `c`, y la cantidad a enviar 1. Es decir, envía 1 carácter a la salida estándar.

Comment: Gracias! estoy aprendiendo a programar y Estamos usando esto para hacer un dibujo con caracteres. tenemos un archivo ft_putchar, un main y otro con toda la funcion. el primer parametro no lo tenia muy claro, no entendia porque 1 ni que opciones puede tener. tampoco termino de entender porque usamos esto y no un simple putchar.

Answer (score 1):

La función [`write`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) es una función del sistema que existe en sistemas operativos Linux.

Al abrir un archivo con [`open` o `create`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) (también funciones del sistema) obtienes un descriptor de archivo.

Existen 3 descriptores especiales que corresponden a los flujos de entrada, salida y error del programa. Puedes encontrarlos en las macros [`STDIN_FILENO`, `STDOUT_FILENO` y `STDERR_FILENO`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdout.3.html).

Entre otras cosas, puedes escribir a un descriptor de archivo con la función `write`.

Recibe como parámetros un descriptor de archivo, un puntero a la información y el tamaño en bytes a escribir que puede coincidir o no con el tamaño de la información.

Por ejemplo, para escribir una cadena de texto a la salida estándar puedes hacerlo así:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "Hola", 4);
}
```

`printf` y `puts` así como otras, son funciones estándar y cada sistema operativo las define a su manera. Es probable que internamente llamen a `write`.